# FLutter high accuracy with location package

Tags: flutter, geolocation, location

For getting the user's location I am using two packages: `location` and `geocoding`. I use location to check if the user has provided location permission or not and to get the `LocationData` which carries the latitude and longitude.

But as far I have seen location does not provide the property called `desiredAccuracy`, which
is much needed for my work.

```
  static void getCurrentLocation() async {
    Location location = new Location();
    bool _serviceEnabled;
    PermissionStatus _permissionGranted;
    LocationData _locationData;

    _serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
    if (!_serviceEnabled) {
      _serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
      if (!_serviceEnabled) {
        return;
      }
    }

    _permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
    if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      _permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
      if (_permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        return;
      }
    }

    _locationData = await location.getLocation();
    double latitude = _locationData.latitude!;
    double longitude = _locationData.longitude!;
    List<geocoding.Placemark> placeMark =
        await geocoding.placemarkFromCoordinates(latitude, longitude);
    String country = placeMark.first.country!;
    String isoCountryCode = placeMark.first.isoCountryCode!;
    print("Country: $country and ISO Country Code: $isoCountryCode");

    print(_locationData);
  }
```

My code till now. Is it possible to get something like desiredAccuracy in `Location`? The only other solution for me would be to use `geolocator` and `permission_handler` packages which will require further configurations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see why you don't want to use geolocator... you've already done the hard work.
Here's how you get the location with desired accuracy

```
 location = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
  forceAndroidLocationManager: true,
  desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best
).timeout(Duration(seconds: 20));
```

Here's how to check if service is enabled

```
var serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
```

And here's how to check if permission is granted

```
    var permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();

    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
    permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      // Permissions are denied, next time you could try
      // requesting permissions again (this is also where
      // Android's shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale
      // returned true. According to Android guidelines
      // your App should show an explanatory UI now.
```

Its clearly written in the documentation here
[geolocatordoc](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator)